# MySQL clarification on sum

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add all of the ips together to count how many have been logged how do i do this
currenty doing. I have put it into a table because of how I am displaying it on the page.

```
foreach($conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip') as $row)
{
    echo $row;
}
```

below is my sql table

```
ip          time
number    12/45/1234
number    12/45/1234
number    12/45/1234
```

Comment: Use `COUNT` instead of `SUM`

Comment: still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Are you looking for `count(distinct ip)`?

Comment: I am probably going to aim overall to do both

Comment: `SELECT date, COUNT(ip) FROM ip GROUP BY ip`

Comment: this does not work either

Comment: can you provide a sample with the output you expect to get?

Comment: http://puu.sh/duYWC/9f984863f5.png
this to the side is the ip box where the ips go to i ahve another box like this hwere i want it to display a number of the distinct and overall

Comment: Do you just want to count how many have been logged? Or otherwise how many rows are in the database? Also is `ip` your table name?

Comment: count how many have been logged or if the other one is simpler and achiveesthe same task then yes and yes it is the name of my table

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to do this? If yes, use COUNT() instead of SUM().

```
 SELECT ip, COUNT(*)
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY ip
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: What exactly do u want to do? Can you please elaborate in complete sentences?

Comment: first of all I want to add all of the ip's together from my table and display a number of how many there are.

Comment: Did you change "TABLE" to your table name?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count how many have been logged we just need the number of records in the table, there isn't a need to sum up ip's:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip;
```

Will get the number of records in the `ip` table. For a future note I don't recommend having the table be the same name as an attribute in the table.

Comment: row 18 is .'<td>' . $row['ip'] . '</td>'

Comment: @user3602591 Run this in your database directly, do you get the result you want?

Comment: yes this works but i want it displayed on my webpage without having me to check on mysql

Comment: row 18 still causing an issue

Comment: @user3602591 The query I showed is just for getting the number of rows, you don't want to replace it with your current query for showing the table in HTML. You just need to `echo` out the result of the query in my answer in PHP, it should only take a single line to do.

Comment: so am i echoing $row ??

Comment: @user3602591 This isn't related to the table you generated. `echo` the result of the query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip;`. For example if you are using `mysqli` functions you would do: `echo mysqli_fetch_row($conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip'))[0];`

Comment: I'm using PDO for this one